# Cant filter from database

Tags: php, filter

I'm having this problem that when I search for a word, it wont show up and this error pops up

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\filterdata.php on line 213).

It only show the table before filtering

```
<?php
include("auth_admin.php");


if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
// search in all table columns
// using concat mysql function
$query = "SELECT * FROM `lcho_dengue_activities` CONCAT(`id`, `month`, `year`, `dengue_ind1`) where `month`= '".$valueToSearch."'";
$search_result = filterTable($query);


}
else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM `lcho_dengue_activities`";
$search_result = filterTable($query);

 }

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
 {
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lcho_login");
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
return $filter_Result;
 }


 ?>

<form action="filterdata.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>dengue_ind1</th>
            </tr>

  <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
         <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['month'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['year'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['dengue_ind1'];?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

`//while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))` is my line 213

I tried changing `$search_result` into `$query` and the same error happens.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query is failing and returning false

Put this after `mysqli_query()` to see what's going on.

```
if (!$filter_Result) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
   exit();
}
```

For more information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`id`, `month`, `year`, `dengue_ind1`) where `month`= 'january'' at line 1